# Как и где лучше хранить API ключ

Tags: javascript, api

Написал приложение суть которого сводится к ajax запросам и получению json. Теперь встал вопрос как хранить API- ключ, который используется в url для этих запросов. Видел похожий вопрос на stack, но на него не было дано внятного ответа.

Приложение будет предназначено для общего пользования

Впервые сталкиваюсь с подобной задачей, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью

Comment: поясните что значит "не было доступа на стороне пользователя"? в куках обычно хранят

Comment: вы же понимаете, что делая запрос, вы все равно открываете этот `api ключ`

Comment: "не было доступа на стороне пользователя" - это невозможно

Comment: если апи ключ _используется в Url_ - то о каком доступе на стороне пользователя идет речь?

Comment: Возможно неверно выразился, поэтому подправил вопрос. Суть в том, как сделать так, чтобы мой api-ключ не был использован кем-то кроме меня?

Comment: Не показывайте его никому, и никто кроме вас использовать не сможет :)

Comment: @russian-stan, нужно больше информации о самом приложении: что это, где запускается, кем?

Comment: Если ключ хранится,например, в какой-нибудь константе, то разве открыв дебагер в браузере я не смогу найти ключ в js файле? Это же очень просто

Comment: @russian-stan если приложением пользуетесь только вы и никому его не показываете, то ничего страшного. Если нет, то нужно больше информации - что это, где запускается, кем, почему так важно держать ключ в секрете от кого-то там. (Невнятный вопрос - невнятные ответы, так-то)

Comment: Приложение для общего пользования представляет из себя SPA по типу кинопоиска, где пользователь может найти интересующий фильм, добавить в избранное, читать описание и пр. функционал. Все запросы используют api-ключ, о котором и идёт речь

Comment: В чем смысл апи ключа? Раз ты его все равно отдаешь клиенту - зачем пытаешься его скрыть?

Comment: "Все запросы" от кого к кому?

Comment: Где бы вы не хранили ключ, его всё равно можно вытащить через дебаггер. Можно хранить ключ на сервере и проксировать все запросы через него

Comment: вы можете ограничивать доступ к апи для подозрительных лиц) которые будут делать много запросов с 1 ip) так же как вариант сделать что-то типа CSRF защиты

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал создать бэкенд прослойку, которая бы запрашивала необходимое API с токеном со стороны сервера, на котором хостится ваше веб-приложение.

Т.е. фронтенд-часть приложения делает запрос к вашему серверу "дай мне список фильмов", далее сервер вызовет внешнее API, а на фронтенд отдаст только лишь готовый результат и контакта браузера пользователя с вашим токеном вообще не произойдёт.

Если из технологий можно применять только `javascript`, то можете поднять `nodejs` сервер и реализовать на `javascript` такую бэкенд-прослойку.

Answer (score -1):

`.env` файлы и `dontenv` пакет, чтоб сделать ключи доступными в коде: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Использование очень простое

Не забудьте добавить `.env` в `.gitignore`.

Answer (score -1):

Скрыть ключ полностью не возможно, но можно ограничить его использование.

Делайте регистрацию пользователя по логину/паролю или соцсети. Вешаете капчу на страницу входа. По логину паролю получаете временный ключ.